# Split and get part of a string by separator in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, substring

Imagine you have a string data column with some separator string.

The substrings can have different length!

For example:

```
abcde@xyz
abc@vwxyz
```

How to output this column as two, or if it is easier just one part (left or right) of the string?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Substring_Index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function; it returns a substring in the left side of the given `count` of occurrences of the given `delimiter`. If the `count` value is negative, then it returns all to the right of the delimiter.

**Demo Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table your_table_name(field_name varchar(255));
insert into your_table_name values('abcde@xyz');
insert into your_table_name values('abc@vwxyz');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
  field_name, 
  Substring_Index(field_name, '@', 1) AS left_part, 
  Substring_Index(field_name, '@', -1) AS right_part
FROM your_table_name;

| field_name | left_part | right_part |
| ---------- | --------- | ---------- |
| abcde@xyz  | abcde     | xyz        |
| abc@vwxyz  | abc       | vwxyz      |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iCxQZTVArq2eXdHHLUi6UR/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)`

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('abcde@xyz', '@', 1);
        -> 'abcde'
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('abcde@xyz', '@', -1);
        -> 'xyz'
```

Source: [MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 12.5 String Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)